# Simultaneously running nginx and apache2

Tags: nginx, apache2

I am running my websites on Ubuntu 14.04 server with nginx.  I would like to set up a mail server (probably using squirrelmail) which uses apache2 (presently not in use).  I intend to keep the port numbers for the web server and mail server entirely different.

Can I do this?  Do I have to do anything out of the ordinary (secret handshakes) to set this up, and if so, what exactly do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's entirely possible. Generally the complications you will have to sort out is both servers trying to listen on the same port, and directory permission issues.

In this case you will have to take precaution to keep Nginx user www-data as root because only root is allowed access to port 80 and 443 (which I'm assuming you are using for your website).

If you work out the kinks though it's entirely possible and has been done many times for situations like yours.

With that said I think it would be a lot of extra work setting up an entire apache webserver just to run squirrelmail. You can configure squirrelmail to work with Nginx and it's not that difficult.

Tutorial [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/running-squirrelmail-on-nginx-lemp-on-debian-squeeze-ubuntu-11.04).

Imho that is the easiest way forward with the fewest possible ways to crash your entire server and be forced to startover. Which brings me to another point.

Before you do any work on a server BACK UP EVERYTHING. Clone your hard drive if you can, if not make sure you get all databases static files config files ect....

It's also best practice to not work on a live production server if you can avoid it. Use a backup in the mean time while you play around with yours.

It will save you a lot of stress to work at a comfortable pace rather than work against the clock of hundreds of customers trying to view your website.

I know that doesn't apply in all cases, but it's a good practice to get into if you can to prepare you for any bigger jobs that come down the road.